# configuring MD5 bgp authentication on solaris 11 using quagga

Tags: solaris, bgp, quagga, md5

I am attempting to configure a BGP router within a solaris zone, using dedicated network interfaces. Upstream provider insists on the use of MD5 authentication.

I have no bgp sessions coming up. I believe I have tracked down the problem to the following

when I restart quagga I get in the log

```
2017/08/28 16:36:34 BGP: can't set TCP_MD5SIG option on socket 7: Operation not applicable
2017/08/28 16:36:34 BGP: can't set TCP_MD5SIG option on socket 7: Operation not applicable
```

and tcpdump is showing that outgoing bgp packets have checksum failures
incoming bgp packets have checksum passes

can someone tell me how to fix this

Comment: Have you looked at [the `tcpkey` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54764/tcpkey-1m.html#REFMAN1Mtcpkey-1m)?

Comment: so you're saying that md5 password signing is only available in solaris 11.3 ?